# How to remove blue border around the button in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, button, styles, border

I'm using `Firefox 10`, `Windows 7` and not sure older version but when I clicked the button, the blue border appears around the button.

I created the example below.

http://jsfiddle.net/dEvKb/58/

I removed the dotted line with css below but I also do not want blue border. I can't figure how to remove it or is it even possible to remove?

```
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner
{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

below didn't work...

```
input[type="button"]:visited
{
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
```

This is evil blue border I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: Visited? Since when do buttons get marked visited? What OS (and theme, if applicable) are you using? Consider providing a screenshot, too...

Comment: I know a:visited so I just gave a try which didn't work

Comment: Ah, well you might try without the `:visited`; it only applies to visited links, and a button is not a link.  I don't get a blue border in Firefox on my machine so I can't test it...

Comment: really? hmm interesting I will see if I can get screenshot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the UI of Firefox, whether themed or none. Not something you got from coding.

If it is troubling you so much you can reset it and define your own style. Here is a reset rule for that.

```
button { background: none transparent; border: none; }
```

[Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/dEvKb/63/)

And you can add your styling on it later on. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dEvKb/64/) for that. You can define custom states for `hover`, `visited` , `active` like the way you want.

Comment: Ah I see, so there is no way to keep the button look as is and only remove blue border... thanks for the demo :)

Answer (score 1):

This blue border (which is OS and theme-dependent) is indicating that the button has keyboard focus.  The dotted outline indicates the same thing.  If you do not care about making your application accessible to people using the keyboard, then you can restyle the button entirely such that there is no unique appearance while the button is focused.

Because the button appearance you're seeing is specified by the OS/browser theme, rather than by CSS, there's no way to tell the browser via CSS to "draw this button as if it were not focused".

Also note the difference between `<button>` and `<input type="button">`; you specify CSS matching both in your first example but not in your second.